# Is there a way to upload media to the Twitter API using the URL of the media resource?

Tags: twitter, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions

I've created an app that allows users to upload their images to a Google Cloud Storage bucket - which is then used in social media sharing previews.

The image is uploaded directly to the bucket from the user's browser - using the Firebase API.

What I also want to do is - when an image is saved - to automatically post that image on my app's twitter feed.

The way I've done this is to use a Cloud Function trigger on Cloud Storage - which downloads the image and then uploads via the Twitter API.

There's essentially an unnecessary double handling of traffic here is there a way to just give the Twitter API the public location of the file and have it source the file directly?

Here's my code for the current solution:

```
class Defferred {

  constructor() {

    const that = this;
    this.prom = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      that.resolve = resolve;
      that.reject = reject;
    });
  }
}

exports.onNewImage = functions.storage.object().onFinalize((object) => {

  const prom = new Defferred();
  bucket.file(object.name).download((err, file, response) => {

    if (err) {
      return prom.reject(err);
    } else {
      twitterClient.post('media/upload', {
        media: file
      }, (err, media, response) => {
        if (!err) {
          let status = {
            status: "Somebody created this at https://geoplanets.io #geometry #geometricart",
            media_ids: media.media_id_string
          }

          twitterClient.post('statuses/update', status, (error, tweet, response) => {
            if (!error) {
              return prom.resolve(response);
            } else {
              return prom.reject(error);
            }

          });
        } else {
          return prom.reject(err);;
        }
      });

    }

  });
  return prom.prom;

});
```

Is there an alternative way of doing this that doesn't involve downloading the file? - A good answer would highlight the relevant parts of the API documentation that highlight how I would go about working this out myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Twitter node api doesn't have a way to simply pass an URL for media upload.  The [example](https://github.com/desmondmorris/node-twitter/tree/master/examples#media) they give shows what you're doing now - sending the full content with the request.

The node client is just a wrapper around the REST API, and if you [read its docs](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/media/upload-media/uploading-media/media-best-practices), you'll see that you have to provide the file content directly to the POST.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**!
We can upload media using **URL of file** by making the **downstream** of a file.

First we need to make Axios request to have a buffer of it then we can pass it with file type using

[twitter-api-v2](https://github.com/PLhery/node-twitter-api-v2/blob/master/doc/v1.md#upload-a-picturevideosubtitle-to-twitter)

use it in this package or REST API

```
    const client = new TwitterApi({
      appKey: CONSUMER_KEY,
      appSecret: CONSUMER_SECRET,
      accessToken: oauth_token,
      accessSecret: oauth_token_secret,
    });
    
    const url = 'URL OF THE FILE';

    const downStream = await axios({
      method: 'GET',
      responseType: 'arraybuffer',
      url: url,
    }).catch(function (error) {
      res.send({error:error});
    });

    const mediaId = await client.v1.uploadMedia(downStream.data,{ mimeType: 'png'}); 
    
    const newTweet = await client.v1.tweet('Hello link tweet!', { media_ids: mediaId });
```

[sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmDjr.png)